# Aligning 9 divs in a 3X3X3 Layout With Link Box Under Each Div

Tags: html, css

Edit #2: I am going to try to implement this:

https://jsfiddle.net/Lcb1eot7/4/

into my giant wall of code and see if I can duplicate the results.

END EDIT #2

EDIT: Alright here is a little fiddle demonstrating the scenario, I did not add many attributes to it so that it is easy to understand. What elements would I need to add to this fiddle in order to achieve my desired effect?

https://jsfiddle.net/Lcb1eot7/3/

END EDIT

I have here a stumper:

What I am trying to accomplish today is this, 9 divs, each div has an a href block underneath it, all aligned in a 3x3x3 div. Here is an example:

```
1 2 3
a a a

4 5 6
a a a

7 8 9
a a a
```

The issue I am encountering is that the link boxes are being pushed over to the right of each div, and not underneath it. If I use:

```
clear:both;
```

It breaks the format, however the link boxes will align properly underneath each div...

I am now experimenting with:

```
display: table;
```

But i still cant get everything aligned the way I want. Here is a screenshot of what my page looks like right now (not all divs appear on screenshot but that should give you the gist of what is going on):

[image: example]

Here is some relevant code:

HTML

```
<div class="industries">
                                    <div class="rowpics1">
                                        <div class="row1a">
                                            <a href="maog.asp">
                                                <div class="fadein">
                                                    <img src="images/oilsunset.jpg" alt="Oil Rigs">
                                                    <img src="images/catloader.png" alt="Loader">
                                                    <img src="images/coalload.jpg" alt="Truck Loading">
                                                </div>
                                                <!--<div class="textspan">
                                                    <span>Mining | Aggregates | Oil & Gas</span>
                                                </div>-->
                                            </a>
                                            <a class="industryClickerLink" href="maog.asp">
                                            <h4 class="industryClickerHeading">More Info</h4>
                                            </a>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="row1b">
                                            <a href="pfee.asp">
                                                <div class="fadein2">
                                                    <img src="images/fastambulance.jpg" alt="Racing Ambulance">
                                                    <img src="images/copcar.JPG" alt="Police Car">
                                                    <img src="images/firetruck.jpg" alt="Fire Truck">
                                                </div>
                                                <!--<div class="textspan">
                                                    <span>Police | Fire | EMS | Enforcement</span>
                                                </div>-->
                                            </a>
                                            <a class="industryClickerLink" href="pfee.asp">
                                            <h4 class="industryClickerHeading">More Info</h4>
                                            </a>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="row1c">
                                            <a href="hctfa.asp">
                                                <div class="fadein3">
                                                    <img src="images/excdrill.jpg" alt="Drilling Excavator">
                                                    <img src="images/loader.jpg" alt="Loader">
                                                    <img src="images/skidder.jpg" alt="Skidder">
                                                </div>
                                                <!--<div class="textspan">
                                                    <span>Heavy Equipment | Construction | Tunnelling | Forestry | Agricultural</span>
                                                </div>-->
                                            </a>
                                            <a class="industryClickerLink" href="hctfa.asp">
                                            <h4 class="industryClickerHeading">More Info</h4>
                                            </a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="rowpics2">
                                        <div class="row2a">
                                            <a href="mswu.asp">
                                                <div class="fadein4">
                                                    <img src="images/snowplow.jpg" alt="Snow Plow">
                                                    <img src="images/sweeper.jpg" alt="Street Sweeper">
                                                    <img src="images/powertruck.jpg" alt="Power Truck">
                                                </div>
                                                <!--<div class="textspan">
                                                    <span>Municipal | Snow Plow | Waste | Utilities</span>
                                                </div>-->
                                            </a>
                                            <a class="industryClickerLink" href="mswu.asp">
                                            <h4 class="industryClickerHeading">More Info</h4>
                                            </a>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="row2b">
                                            <a href="mttrf.asp">
                                                <div class="fadein5">
                                                    <img src="images/forkliftwood.jpg" alt="ForkLift">
                                                    <img src="images/transportslab.jpg" alt="Coal Train">
                                                    <img src="images/transtruck.jpg" alt="Transport Truck">
                                                </div>
                                                <!--<div class="textspan">
                                                    <span>Material Handling & Forklift | Transport & Trucking</span>
                                                </div>-->
                                            </a>
                                            <a class="industryClickerLink" href="mttrf.asp">
                                            <h4 class="industryClickerHeading">More Info</h4>
                                            </a>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="row2c">
                                            <a href="ma.asp">
                                                <div class="fadein6">
                                                    <img src="images/helicopter.jpg" alt="Helicopter">
                                                    <img src="images/tugboat.jpg" alt="Tugboat">
                                                    <img src="images/coaltrain.jpg" alt="Coal Train">
                                                </div>
                                                <!--<div class="textspan">
                                                    <span>Marine | Aviation | Rail</span>
                                                </div>-->
                                            </a>
                                            <a class="industryClickerLink" href="ma.asp">
                                            <h4 class="industryClickerHeading">More Info</h4>
                                            </a>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="rowpics3">
                                            <div class="row3a">
                                                <a href="ti.asp">
                                                    <div class="fadein7">
                                                        <img src="images/infraredcam.jpg" alt="Infrared Camera">
                                                        <img src="images/thermalbear.jpg" alt="Bear Thermal Vision">
                                                        <img src="images/thermalcam.jpg" alt="Thermal Camera">
                                                    </div>
                                                    <!--<div class="textspan">
                                                        <span>Thermal Imaging</span>
                                                    </div>-->
                                                </a>
                                                <a class="industryClickerLink" href="ti.asp">
                                                <h4 class="industryClickerHeading">More Info</h4>
                                                </a>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="row3b">
                                                <a href="sb.asp">
                                                    <div class="fadein8">
                                                        <img src="images/Flir_Logo_287.jpg" alt="FLIR">
                                                        <img src="images/Brigade-logo.jpg" alt="BRIGADE">
                                                        <img src="images/hellalogo.jpg" alt="HELLA">
                                                    </div>
                                                    <!--<div class="textspan">
                                                        <span>Specific Brands</span>
                                                    </div>-->
                                                </a>
                                                <a class="industryClickerLink" href="sb.asp">
                                                <h4 class="industryClickerHeading">More Info</h4>
                                                </a>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="row3c">
                                                <a href="http://provix.net/crv/crviis.dll?mtd=newstart">
                                                    <div class="fadein9">
                                                        <img src="images/sitescreen1.png" alt="Store Snapshot">
                                                        <img src="images/sitescreen2.png" alt="Store Snapshot 2">
                                                        <img src="images/pdfscreen.png" alt="PDF Snapshot">
                                                    </div>
                                                    <!--<div class="textspan">
                                                        <span>Store</span>
                                                    </div>-->
                                                </a>
                                                <a class="industryClickerLink" href="http://provix.net/crv/crviis.dll?mtd=newstart">
                                                <h4 class="industryClickerHeading">More Info</h4>
                                                </a>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
```

CSS

```
.rowpics1 a {
margin-top: 20px;
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
display: table;
table-layout: fixed;
}

.rowpics2 a {
margin-top: 20px;
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
display: table;
table-layout: fixed;
}

.rowpics3 a {
margin-top: 20px;
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
display: table;
table-layout: fixed;
}

.industryClickerLink {
/* Permalink - use to edit and share this gradient: http://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#b11733+0,b7171a+99 */
background: #b11733;
/* Old browsers */
background: -moz-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, #b11733 0%, #b7171a 99%);
/* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(radial, center center, 0px, center center, 100%, color-stop(0%, #b11733), color-stop(99%, #b7171a));
/* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, #b11733 0%, #b7171a 99%);
/* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, #b11733 0%, #b7171a 99%);
/* Opera 12+ */
background: -ms-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, #b11733 0%, #b7171a 99%);
/* IE10+ */
background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, #b11733 0%, #b7171a 99%);
/* W3C */
filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#b11733', endColorstr='#b7171a', GradientType=1);
/* IE6-9 fallback on horizontal gradient */
display: table-cell;
width: 290px;
height: 30px;
position: absolute;
padding-bottom: 5px;
overflow: hidden;
float: left;
bottom: 0;
}
.row1a a {
float: left;
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
display: table-cell;

}

.row1b a {
position: relative;
float: left;
overflow: hidden;
display: table-cell;
}

.row1c a {
display: table-cell;
position: relative;
float: left;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

There is more code but I think that should get the point across. So does anyone know whats going on here? What can I do to get these aligned properly and using a cross browser compatible method? Thank you for the help.

And to clarify, I am trying to get the "MORE INFO" boxes underneath each picture square.

Comment: I did not include the "fadein" div in the CSS but it looks like this (it is a JS image transition thing):                                                                    .fadein {
    position: relative;
    width: 290px;
    height: 190px;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

Comment: A ***small*** demo just enough to demonstrate the problem would be of more use than the mega codedump.

Comment: Sure let me create a demo!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So... I finally found the issue.... the simplest thing that took me almost an entire day to find. I broke everything down and wrote it all from scratch and then boom, I saw what my mistake was. In the CSS I was calling all of the row1a,row1b,row1c, etc. as row1a a, row1b a, row1c a. Each box is a link but I did not realize I had placed the a tag alongside them in the CSS.

At the same time, I also cleaned up all of my code as I realized how redundant it was.

In summary row1a, row1b,row1c, etc. now look like this:

```
rowBox {
    width:290px;
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my update to your 1st edits fiddle to achieve the effect you're asking about: https://jsfiddle.net/Lcb1eot7/5/

To break it down:

1) I gave each 'littleBoxOfFun#' div a common class of 'lbf'.

```
<div class="littleBoxOfFun1">
```

Becomes

```
<div class="littleBoxOfFun1 lbf">
```

2) In the stylesheet I targeted the lbf class and added a float:left, and a right margin of 10px for visibility.

```
.lbf{
    float:left;
    margin-right:10px;
}
```

3) Because every 3rd lbf div does not need any margin to the right I used an nth-child selector to target every 3rd lbf div and remove the margin.

```
.lbf:nth-child(3n+0){
    margin-right:0;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Awesome suggestion Justin, I may try this in a future project! Thanks for your help and time.